# How do I change Genymotion physical keyboard to type scandic letters?

Tags: keyboard, genymotion

I have enabled scandics (äöå) on-screen keyboard and they work, but when I type them from physical keyboard they do not work, nothing comes out. All english keyboard keys do work.

Comment: have you found an answer on this question? I'm using Genymotion as well, and can't find a solution that allow to type with physical keyboard in other languages than English. It types numbers, instead of a real letter, even after I installed a language.

Comment: Might be this one could help Memu: http://www.memuplay.com/blog/index.php/2016/02/19/how-to-input-multi-language/